# javascript/angularjs - order of function calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, angularjs-ng-click

I have a button that has 4 functions attached to it:

```
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle= "modal" href="#booking" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="createResource(); cancelFirstModal(); confirmNumberOfBooking(); showSecondModal(); " >Create Bookings</button>
```

upon `ng-click`, `createResource()` is to be called first, then `confirmNumberOfBookings()` but my console output in safari says otherwise:

[image: console log]

```
    $scope.createResource = function () {
        console.log('create is called');
        $http.post('/api/v1/resource', $scope.newResource).then(function (response) {
            console.log('post is called');
        });
    };

    $scope.confirmNumberOfBooking = function (){
        //$scope.numberOfBookings = 3;
        console.log('confirm is called');
        $scope.newResource.booking = [
            {
                startDateTime: "datetime",
                endDateTime: "datetime"
            }
        ];

        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.newResource.numberOfBookings; i++){
            $scope.newResource.booking.push({startDateTime: "datetime",endDateTime: "datetime"});
        }
    };
```

My question is, why does `$http.post` get called last? It is declared technically before `confirmNumberOfBookings()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order of call is not how it's reported or output in console.

$http.post is called just after console.log('create is called').

$http.post returns a Promise that will be resolved to a response object when the request succeeds or fails hence you get output 'post is called' only when promise is resolved and doesn't indicates the order of call.

Let me know if you still unsure.

Comment: that makes sense! is there a way to call `confirmNumberOfBookings()` prior to the promise being resolved?

Comment: Yes there is, my suggestion would be to only call one function on ng-click and control the flow in that function or the logic instead of depending on the flow with ng-click function order.

So for example ng-click="bookingConfirmation"
$scope.bookingConfirmation = ()=>{ //createResource call if possible make it a promise so when promise is resolved then only call 2nd function and so on.  }

Comment: Also depends if your functions are synch or async functions. if they are sync  functions then you can rely on the order they are called but if they not make sure you use promises so that only do next step once previous function call is resolved and it's good to make call to next function. Check this fiddle for example. http://jsfiddle.net/perdeepOsingh/bu0ooz6b/2/